# Issues deleting discrete vals from transformed sparse vector list using regex in python

Tags: python-3.x, sparse-matrix, python-re

I'm trying to remove all values with index vals 1, 2, and 3, from a string list like
['1:1', '2:100.0', '3:100.0',...]. The data is in sparse vector format and was loaded as a pandas dataframe. I used an online regex tester to match the first three positions of this list with success.

But as it exists in my program, the same regex doesn't work. On running:

```
data = pd.read_csv("c:\data.csv")

for index, row in data.itterrows():
    line = parseline(row)

def parseline(line):
    line = line.values.flatten() # data like: ['1:1 2:100.0 3:100.0...']
    stringLine = listToString(line) # data like: 1:1 2:100.0 3:100.0... 
    splitLine = stringLine.split(" ") # data like: ['1:1', '2:100.0', '3:100.0',...]

    remove = re.findall(r"'1:1'|'[2,3]:\d+.\d+'")
    splitLine.remove(remove)
    print(splitLine)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide the `findall` function with a string. From the documentation: `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I ended up using the re.sub() method on the stringLine object (string), rather than the re.findall() method on the splitLine object (list). Overall was an issue of method not being able to operate on a list.

Answer (score 0):

The splitLine object was actually a list, but the re.findall() method (and re.sub() method, which was what was actually used) requires a string, instead of a list. Was just operating on the wrong data structure. Ultimately:

```
def parseline(line):
    line = line.values.flatten().tolist()
    stringLine = listToString(line)
    stringLine = re.sub(r"1:1 |2:\d+.\d+ ", "", stringLine)
    ...
```

did the trick.